# Browse file in visual c++ windows form application

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008

I want a browse option button into my form application which should browse the file till the path and get the only file name(which has been selected) into a text box.

Please reply..

Thanks,
Amrita

Comment: Hello amrita, welcome to SO. Your question in the current form will most probably get closed. If you want to avoid it, you can improve your question following this FAQ topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Add a button to your form and then on click of the button write this code with appropriate filter and extension of file which you want to open. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx)

```
static char szFilter[] =
   "Chart Files (*.xlc)|*.xlc|Worksheet Files (*.xls)|*.xls|All Files (*.*)|*.*||";   
CFileDialog FileDlg(TRUE, ".xls", NULL, 0, szFilter);
if( FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK ) {
   CString strFile = FileDlg.GetFileName();
   ...
}
```